# Get response from multiple Web Api end points in an efficient manner

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task

I am new to ASP.Net Web API. I need to achieve the following. I have two web API end points 
http://someurl.azurewebsites.net/api/recipe/recipes This returns the recipes that are available.
[ID, Name, Type]

http://someurl.azurewebsites.net/api/recipe/{ID} This returns the recipe with [ID, Ingredients, Cost....]

I need to build a application to get the cheapest recipe in a timely manner.

I am able to get the desired result using the following code but at times it crashes and throws the following exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
How can I achieve this in an efficient manner both using Controller or Javascript.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        List<Receipe> receipelist = new List<Receipe>();
        var baseAddress = "http://someurl.azurewebsites.net/api/recipe/recipes";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-access-token", "sjd1HfkjU83");
            using (var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress).Result)
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    var Receipes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Receipe>>(jsonString.Substring(jsonString.IndexOf("Receipes") + 8, (jsonString.Length - jsonString.IndexOf("Receipes") - 9)));
                    if (Receipes != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Receipe Receipe in Receipes)
                        {
                            var baseAddress1 = "http://someurl.azurewebsites.net/api//api/recipe/" + Receipe.ID;

                            using (var client1 = new HttpClient())
                            {
                                client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-access-token", "sjd1HfkjU83");
                                using (var response1 = client1.GetAsync(baseAddress1).Result)
                                {
                                    var jsonString1 = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                                    receipelist.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Receipe>(jsonString1));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }


        return View(receipelist);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. Without experimenting, it is not really possible to say which would be the most efficient way. Or may be we really don't need to be so efficient. Consider the following steps:

- Try to cache the result of the first response, i.e list of recipes available (Endpoint #1). You could cache that for 'x' timespan depending on your business requirement. That will most likely save you a first trip. My guess is that the 'list of available recipes' will not change very often; so you could probably cache that for a while(hours/days?). You could use a dictionary object  as a data structure and cache this.
- If you have control of the Endpoint #2, then I'd recommend providing an api that takes in 'list of ids' instead of just one id. So in essence you are asking Endpoint#2 to return 'a list of recipes with price' in one api call rather than looping for each recipe at a time. You could probably cache this data as well, depending on how often the price changes. My guess is this won't change very often either. When you get the 'list of prices with id', efficiently plug the price info to existing dictionary.
- When you hit an exception when making an api calls, you could always return the stale data to the users instead of not displaying any data/errors. Be sure to let the users know by labeling in the UI something like "Recipe as of 2 hours ago".
- With the above changes, your application should be able to perform well and in the worst case, display stale data.

Keep in mind that depending on the problem domain, we don't always have to be up to the second/minute consistent with the data. In real life and in reality the data on the internet is always stale. For example, by the time your end users sees the price and decides to click to buy a recipe, the price of the recipe might have already changed!

Hope this helps.